# How to compute the real window size in Mac Catalyst in macOS 11

Tags: mac-catalyst, macos-big-sur

I ported a game to macOS using Mac Catalyst. The game content doesn't dynamically resize so I forced a fixed 3:4 aspect ratio (like an iPad on portrait) at the start of the app. I added this to my AppDelegate class:

```swift
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        #if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
                        /* some margin */
            let titleHeight: CGFloat = 34 * 4
            UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.compactMap { $0 as? UIWindowScene }.forEach { windowScene in
                windowScene.titlebar?.titleVisibility = .hidden
                /* screen was always 1920x1080 in macOS Catalina */
                let height = windowScene.screen.nativeBounds.height - titleHeight
                let width = 3 * height / 4
                windowScene.sizeRestrictions?.minimumSize = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
                windowScene.sizeRestrictions?.maximumSize = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
            }
        #endif
    }
```

That works in fixing the aspect, but the window looked small in a 15-inch MacBook Pro. Apple confirmed that Catalina always reported `1920x1080`, [read here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/652276?answerId=617896022#617896022).

In macOS 11 that got fixed, so now in a 15-inch MacBook Pro, for the default Retina display settings, I get:

```
nativeBounds: 3360x2100
bounds: 1680x1050
nativeScale: 2
scale: 2
```

However, if I set the height in sizeRestrictions fixed to 1050, the window is too short. If I set it to 2100, the window is approximately 30% taller than the screen and out of bounds.

I read in the [UI Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/overview/mac-catalyst/) that Mac Catalyst apps get scaled 77% down, so a height for approximately `1400` seems to work here. Is there a way to get this scale programatically?

At the moment, I hard-coded `1.3 * screen.bounds.height` in the code. I'm not 100% that is the correct value for `sizeRestrictions` though, or if it just happens to be right in this screen.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet is to hack your way to setting NSWindow’s [contentAspectRatio](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419148-contentaspectratio?language=objc) property, which will lock your content to your desired aspect ratio. (There is also an `NSWindow.contentRatio` property, which will limit the *window’s* size, but I think `contentAspectRatio` is what you want.)

1. Get the [Dynamic library](https://github.com/mhdhejazi/Dynamic) to make the following easier.
2. Get the AppKit NSWindow from your current UIWindow:

```
extension UIWindow {
    var nsWindow: NSObject? {
        var nsWindow = Dynamic.NSApplication.sharedApplication.delegate.hostWindowForUIWindow(self)
        if #available(macOS 11, *) {
            nsWindow = nsWindow.attachedWindow
        }
        return nsWindow.asObject
    }
}
```

3. Once `window.nsWindow` is non-nil (you may need to wait for viewDidAppear), set its contentAspectRatio to 4:3:

```
Dynamic(view.window?.nsWindow).contentAspectRatio = CGSize(width: 4, height: 3)
```

Comment: I should mention: Dynamic makes this easy to do in *Swift*. If you’re using Objective-C (or don’t mind bridging to ObjC), then all the code above can be done pretty easily with NSClassFromString.